# Run full kde desktop remotely on another Linux box?

Tags: remote-desktop, x11, kde

I have two identical Linux boxes, A and B, both have KDE installed. Sitting in front of the screen of A, I'd like to have B's full KDE desktop appear on A's screen, using X11 (not VNC). Presumably that can be done, but how?

I am aware of DISPLAY etc to have individual applications' windows show up, but I'm asking about B's entire desktop, preferably taking over the entire screen on A.

Comment: Sounds like XDMCP is what you are asking for.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using [x2go](http://wiki.x2go.org/doku.php).

It's not using X11 but NX protocol (which do X11 compression behind the scenes). Authentication is based on SSH.

Answer (score 1):

Your goal is unclear.

If you mean accessing an existing session running on, say display :0 but don't care about it being shared via VNC, then [x11vnc](http://www.karlrunge.com/x11vnc/) is the way to go.

If you mean accessing another computer's X session via a thin-client like device, have a look at [Xdmx](http://dmx.sourceforge.net/).

A sort of middle ground seems to be [Xpra](https://www.xpra.org/).

Please clarify your goals.

Comment: I'd like to pretend that I'm sitting in front of B's monitor, but I'm really sitting in front of A's monitor. It doesn't have to be an existing session; B's monitor may well be blank or sitting at a login prompt.